# How to handle long text value in bootstrap tooltip?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very long string in my tooltip (string1,string2) (Note: there is a comma in between and string1 and string2 are very long).

When I display it, the tooltip can't display the full long string. Just wonder which css property I can change to make the tooltip display a long string properly?

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="center">
   <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas bibendum ac felis id commodo. Etiam mauris purus, fringilla id tempus in, mollis vel orci. Duis ultricies at erat eget iaculis.">Hover here please</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.center {
  margin: 20em auto;
  width: 400px;
}


/*Change the size here*/
div.tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 450px;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("a").tooltip({
    'selector': '',
    'placement': 'top',
    'container':'body'
  });
});

$('.auto-tooltip').tooltip();
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/qonuwa/1/)

Comment: Is your class supposed to be `tooltip `? Your css had the class `tolltip`.

Answer (score 3):

CSS has a property break the longer words. Its called `word-break` or `word-wrap`

```
div.tooltip
{
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

OR

```
div.tooltip
{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Here is the demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/cwv5r453/